# Theme Switching Using PrimeVue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I want to change the theme using Prime Vue with out usnig the `<link id="lara-light-indigo" rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css">` in the index.html file

Iam running my theme using the `import "primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";` in the main.js file I want to use this to change the theme in the Topbar.vue page

```
import { usePrimeVue } from 'primevue/config';

  const PrimeVue = usePrimeVue();
let currentTheme = ref(null);
if ( localStorage.getItem('theme') != null) {
       currentTheme.value = localStorage.getItem('theme');
       toggleThemeDark();
    }else {
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'lara-light-indigo');
        currentTheme.value = 'lara-light-indigo'
        toggleThemeDark();
    }
function toggleTheme () {
    
    const newTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'lara-light-indigo' ? 'lara-dark-indigo' : 'lara-light-indigo';
  PrimeVue.changeTheme(localStorage.getItem('theme'), newTheme, 'lara-light-indigo', () => {
    currentTheme = newTheme;
    document.querySelector('.moon').classList.toggle('sun');
   
  });   
  localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);

};

function toggleThemeDark () {
    if(currentTheme.value == 'lara-dark-indigo'){
        PrimeVue.changeTheme('lara-light-indigo', 'lara-dark-indigo', 'lara-light-indigo', () => {
    document.querySelector('.moon');
   
  }); 
    }else{
        PrimeVue.changeTheme('lara-dark-indigo', 'lara-light-indigo', 'lara-light-indigo', () => {
            document.querySelector('.dark');
    document.querySelector('.moon').classList.toggle('sun');
   
  }); 
    }
};
<div class="dark" @click="toggleTheme">
        <div class="tdnn" :class="{ 'day': currentTheme === 'lara-light-indigo' }">
            <div class="moon" :class="{ 'moon': currentTheme === 'lara-dark-indigo' }"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I was using this code while I was using the link tag at the index.html and was working good but i need to make something different so I update the prime vue or something like that no need to go to index.html and change something

Answer (score 0):

you can dynamically change the theme without using the  tag in the index.html file.

```
import { usePrimeVue } from 'primevue/config';
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const PrimeVue = usePrimeVue();
    const currentTheme = ref(null);

    if (localStorage.getItem('theme') != null) {
      currentTheme.value = localStorage.getItem('theme');
      toggleThemeDark();
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'lara-light-indigo');
      currentTheme.value = 'lara-light-indigo';
      toggleThemeDark();
    }

    function toggleTheme() {
      const newTheme =
        localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'lara-light-indigo'
          ? 'lara-dark-indigo'
          : 'lara-light-indigo';

      PrimeVue.changeTheme(
        localStorage.getItem('theme'),
        newTheme,
        'lara-light-indigo',
        () => {
          currentTheme.value = newTheme;
          document.querySelector('.moon').classList.toggle('sun');
        }
      );

      localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
    }

    function toggleThemeDark() {
      if (currentTheme.value === 'lara-dark-indigo') {
        PrimeVue.changeTheme(
          'lara-light-indigo',
          'lara-dark-indigo',
          'lara-light-indigo',
          () => {
            document.querySelector('.moon');
          }
        );
      } else {
        PrimeVue.changeTheme(
          'lara-dark-indigo',
          'lara-light-indigo',
          'lara-light-indigo',
          () => {
            document.querySelector('.dark');
            document.querySelector('.moon').classList.toggle('sun');
          }
        );
      }
    }

    return {
      currentTheme,
      toggleTheme,
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: But iam getting this 2 errors 

1)
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function 
  at <AppTopbar> 
  at <AppLayout onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
Promise.then (async)  
(anonymous) @ main.js?t=1704207711223:72
Show 47 more frames
2)
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'cloneNode')
    at Object.switchTheme [as changeTheme] (config.esm.js:164:40)
    at toggleThemeDark (AppTopbar.vue:53:18)
    at setup (AppTopbar.vue:28:8)